# Incorporating na.rm=TRUE into Summarise_Each for Multiple Functions in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

So I have a dplyr table movie_info_comb from which I am calculating various statistics on one column metascore.  Here is the code:

```
summarise_each_(movie_info_comb, funs(min,max,mean,sum,sd,median,IQR),"metascore")
```

How do incorporate na.rm=TRUE?  I've only seen examples for which one statistic is being calculated and I'd hate to have to repeat this 5 times (one for each function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try `summarise_each(movie_info_comb, funs(min=min(., na.rm=TRUE), max= max(., na.rm=TRUE)), metascore)`  Some functions may not have the `na.rm=TRUE` argument, so it is better to specify for each function.

Comment: But is there a way to use one statement that passes `na.rm=TRUE` to every function, rather than having to separately specify `na.rm=TRUE` in each function?

Comment: Thanks @akun,  that looks like the most expedient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with lazy evaluation

```
library(lazyeval)

na.rm = function(FUN_string)
  lazy(FUN(., na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    interp(FUN = FUN_string %>% as.name)

na.rm.apply = function(FUN_strings)
  FUN_strings %>% 
  lapply(na.rm) %>%
  setNames(FUN_strings)

mtcars %>%
  select(mpg) %>%
  summarize_each(
    c("min","max","mean","sum","sd","median","IQR") %>%
      na.rm.apply)
```